# HTTP downloadable file serving

Tags: http, go, http-headers

I want  to serve a downloadable file , but when i tested it i am able to download file but downloaded file is blank. I checked in IDE the file has content but downloaded file is blank and even i am getting file size as 0. Please help.

File info :- file is csv and it contains one line of field name only.

```
 func SendFileToClient(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request,file string){

    downloadBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    fmt.Println("file to be sent ",file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unable to download the file: %v", err)
    }

    mime := http.DetectContentType(downloadBytes)
    fileSize := len(string(downloadBytes))
   fmt.Println("mime is ",mime ," filesize ",fileSize)
    //Generate the server headers
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "octet-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+file+"")
    w.Header().Set("Expires", "0")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(fileSize))
    w.Header().Set("Content-Control", "private, no-transform, no-store, must-revalidate")


    
    //// force it down the client's.....
    http.ServeContent(w, r, file, time.Now(), bytes.NewReader(downloadBytes))



}
```

Comment: Are you sure ioutil.ReadFile doesn't return an error? You just move on as if nothing happened after you print the error.

Comment: No it does'nt return any error , but ioutil.ReadFile function is reading 0 bytes , even the path is correct .

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out i was using  "defer writer.flush()" for csv file creation and in same function i was calling above sender function , due to defer file was not saved and it was sending blank file and after sending blank file it was saving file.  Therefore i removed defer and put (writer.flush )function at where i wanted to save my file. After saving the file i called my sender function and it worked.